# Delete project from TFS online with VS2010 Professional (TFSDeleteProject isn't on my computer!)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, project

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and I've been using the TFS service at visualstudio.com. I've read [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635889/delete-team-project-from-free-team-foundation-service) as well as other things around the web. However, TFSDeleteProject doesn't seem to be part of my development toolset.

So, how can I delete a project?

Comment: Did you look in here?  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: Looks like it's probably there, since I have the same installation at work as at home (or very close). Microsoft's website said it was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC... I didn't even think to simply perform a search! Heh. Post that as the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You should also have a Visual Studio 20XX Command Prompt icon in the start menu/screen.  Run that and it'll put this directory in the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TFS @ visualstudio.com  is 2012 based, it's best (and sometimes required)  to perform administration functions using [Team Explorer 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656).

Regardless of whether you have 2010 or 2012 installed you'll find the EXE you are looking for in:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\Common7\IDE*
```

*Substitute (x86) and XX.0 as needed

Additionally you should have a Visual Studio 20XX Command Prompt shortcut in your start menu.  Running that will create a CMD session with the above directory in the path.

Comment: Turns out that the TFSDeleteProject.exe that is included with VS2010 can't delete projects on visualstudio.com.

Comment: I suspected as much. "(and sometimes required)"  Just install Team Explorer 2012 (link provided) and run it from that directory.

Comment: What if I'm running a Mac and using a git based project? :)

Comment: @Zenox- You should post that as a new question.  FWIW if you have an MSDN subscribtion you can download Team Explorer Everywhere 2013 @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/json/GetDownloadRequest?brand=MSDN&locale=en-us&fileId=56203&activexDisabled=false&akamaiDL=true