# Delete project from Visual Studio Team Services (from a mac)

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Similar to this questions:
[Delete project from TFS online with VS2010 Professional (TFSDeleteProject isn't on my computer!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961041/delete-project-from-tfs-online-with-vs2010-professional-tfsdeleteproject-isnt)

Except in this instance, I'm using the Git feature of tfs online for code versioning and using a mac. I suppose I could setup a virtual machine and install Team Explorer, but that seems like a bit of a hassle. I'm just curious if anyone else has a suggestion on how else I could delete the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete Team Projects via the Web interface.  Click the gear icon in the upper-right to bring up the settings interface.  Navigate to the Project Collection, then you can click the little arrow next to each project to Delete it.

[image]